# Why is xcode/lldb/x86 not executing this correctly?

Tags: xcode, x86, lldb

Swift program runs well.  In generated code for swift_rt_swift_release, you find:

```
SystemSensor`swift_rt_swift_release:
->  0x100002c22 <+18>: leaq   0x91573f(%rip), %rax      ; _swift_release
    0x100002c29 <+25>: movq   (%rsp), %rdi
    0x100002c2d <+29>: callq  *(%rax)
```

I can set a breakpoint at the leaq instruction and use si to step and it works peachy.  However, if I run the program for a bit, hit a breakpoint in the source and then single-step through the source, eventually the indirect callq will break on an invalid address.

The leaq instruction >should< be doing nothing more than adding the value of rip (of the next instruction) to 0x91573f. My math says that's 0x0000000100918368. Yet,

```
(lldb) reg wri rip 0x100002c22
(lldb) si
(lldb) reg read
General Purpose Registers:
       rax = 0x00000000cc918368
       ...
```

And, it seems like this is a permanent change: if I set rax to the correct value and continue, it will break (with invalid address) at the same place with the same bad value.

This is quite reproducible. Oddly, the difference between the correct and the incorrect values of rax is 0x0000000034000000

I'm at a loss, here. Any ideas?

macbook pro/macos 10.12.4/xcode 8.3.2

Comment: I couldn't get the behavior you describe to happen.  If you have a reproducible case of this, can you file a bug as described here: https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. Unfortunately, my case involves a pile o' proprietary code.  I'll see what I can come up with. I've only encountered this when using the step-over button in xcode over some statements including a function return. Since the code in question has to do with releasing references, I suspect that the function-return may confuse things...